# nativescript actionbar left margin

Tags: android, android-actionbar, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

The [nativescript actionbar example shown here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#using-a-custom-title-view) is not functioning when trying out myself in a Nativescript + Angular2 app. An additional margin to the left is added which I have much trouble to remove. The result of the test is shown below (with another image than the one from the link).

[image]

The relevant part of the code:

**HTML code:**

```
<ActionBar title="test">
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal"
    ios:horizontalAlignment="center"
    android:horizontalAlignment="left">
        <Image src="~/assets/img/image.png" class="action-image"></Image>
        <Label text="ativeScript"  class="action-label"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ActionBar>
```

**CSS:**

```
.action-image {
    width: 40;
    height: 40;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.action-label {
    color: #3C5AFD;
    font-size: 24;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you provide some more info about the Emulator and its API level. I tested the given code on my side with latest NativeScript 3,0, however, this issue with the left margin is not reproducible. It would help if you could provide some sample project